# Permission denied on owned file

Tags: linux, chmod, permissions

I'm having issues setting permissions for a specific user.

I have a directory `/srv/git/` in which I'm trying to create a sub-directory `test`  containing one file `testfile` (owned by `www:www-data`). `testfile` should only readable and writable by user and group and nobody else.

```
[root@bartplatak ~]# cd /srv/git
[root@bartplatak git]# mkdir test && touch test/testfile
[root@bartplatak git]# chown -R www:www-data test
[root@bartplatak git]# chmod o= test/testfile
[root@bartplatak git]# chmod -R ug=rw test
[root@bartplatak git]# sync
[root@bartplatak git]# su www
```

However for some unknown reason, I cannot `cd` into the directory (and listing it shows very incomplete information)

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/srv/git

bash-4.1$ ls -la test
ls: cannot access test/.: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/testfile: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/..: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? testfile

bash-4.1$ cd test
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

What strikes me as odd is the fact that `..` shows incomplete information despite being accessible (`drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Mar  1 19:02 .`).

**EDIT**:
The machine I'm running this on is a VPS with `CentOS release 6.5 (Final)`.

```
Linux bartplatak.com 2.6.32-042stab078.28 #1 SMP Mon Jul 8 10:17:22 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

SELinux is (as far as I can see) disabled

```
[root@bartplatak ~]# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Permissions on the directory (and parents) are set as

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Mar  1 19:02 /
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Mar  1 14:16 /srv
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Mar  1 19:02 /srv/git
drw-rw-r-x 2 www  www-data 4096 Mar  1 19:02 /srv/git/test
-rw-rw---- 1 www  www-data    0 Mar  1 19:02 /srv/git/test/testfile

[root@bartplatak git]# stat /srv/git/test
  File: `/srv/git/test'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 5ae0b691h/1524676241d   Inode: 404068      Links: 2
Access: (0665/drw-rw-r-x)  Uid: (  497/     www)   Gid: (  496/www-data)


[root@bartplatak git]# stat /srv/git/test/testfile
  File: `/srv/git/test/testfile'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 5ae0b691h/1524676241d   Inode: 404071      Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (  497/     www)   Gid: (  496/www-data)
```

After `su www`, `id` shows `uid=497(www) gid=497(www) groups=497(www),496(www-data)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious problem is that `/srv/git/test` does not have the executable `x` bit set for owner and group. Thus it [is not possible to traverse the directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/20805).

Resolve the issue with:

```
chmod ug+x /srv/git/test
```